# Compiling an ASP program through Xampp

Tags: asp.net, xampp

Can i use XAMPP apache to compile my ASP files. If so, please tell how ?

Any link or document will do

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you have XAMPP and [ASP Installer](http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=175077) already installed

open up C:\xampp\htdocs\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

add this between the `<IfModule alias_module></IfModule>` tags

```
#asp.net

LoadModule aspdotnet_module "modules/mod_aspdotnet.so"
AddHandler asp.net asax ascx ashx asmx aspx axd config cs csproj licx rem resources resx soap vb vbproj vsdisco webinfo 
<IfModule mod_aspdotnet.cpp> 
  AspNetMount /SampleASP "c:/xampp/asp_docs" 
  Alias /SampleASP "c:/xampp/asp_docs"
  <Directory "c:/xampp/asp_docs"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks ExecCGI 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.aspx 
  </Directory> 
  AliasMatch /aspnet_client/system_web/(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/(.*) "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v$1.$2.$3/ASP.NETClientFiles/$4" 
  <Directory "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v*/ASP.NETClientFiles"> 
    Options FollowSymlinks 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
</IfModule>

#asp.net
```

Now restart your Apache server

Also you need to keep your asp files in  C:\xampp\asp_docs

Comment: Check out [this](http://www.todayinwindows.com/forum/index.php?topic=574.msg8825#msg8825) thread maybe you will get your answer there

Answer (score 0):

If your xampp is running then stop the server and do these setps..

-> Firstly find xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

-> Find Listen :80 …. Change to 8080

-> Find [ServerName localhost:80] change it to 8080

-> Then Find xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf

-> Find Listen 443…. Change to 442 [This changes the SSL (HTTPS) port to 442 (or again, your port of choice).]

-> Start xampp server

-> Open browser type [localhost:8080]

Enjoy Both Servers at the same time